# Parsing '<' sign using simple html dom with phpword

Tags: php, simple-html-dom, phpword

using `simplehtmldom`, Its all fine with all the symbols parsing but When there is `'<'` sign appears in the text like `"p<10"` It gives error. can any both help me on parsing `'<'` using `simplehtmldom`.

```
public function contentWord($section, $html_data) {
    $html_dom = new \simple_html_dom();
    $html_dom->load('<html><body>' . $html_data . '</body></html>');
    foreach ($html_dom->find('img') as $image):
        $pcs = explode(";", $image->src);
        $pcsExtension = explode("/", $pcs[0]);
        $ext = $pcsExtension[1];
        $file = '/public/temp/' . $this->guid() . "." . $ext;
        $fullpath = base_path() . $file;
        $base64string = explode(",", $pcs[1]);
        \File::put($fullpath, base64_decode($base64string[1]));
        $image->src = $file;
    endforeach;

    $html_dom_array = $html_dom->find('html', 0)->children();

    $initial_state = array(
        'phpword_object' => &$PHPWord, // Must be passed by reference.
        'base_root' => "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
        'base_path' => $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
        'current_style' => array('size' => '11', 'name' => 'arial', 'align' => 'justify'), // The PHPWord style on the top element - may be inherited by descendent elements.
        'parents' => array(0 => 'body'), // Our parent is body.
        'list_depth' => 0, // This is the current depth of any current list.
        'context' => 'section', // Possible values - section, footer or header.
        'pseudo_list' => TRUE, // NOTE: Word lists not yet supported (TRUE is the only option at present).
        'pseudo_list_indicator_font_name' => 'Wingdings', // Bullet indicator font.
        'pseudo_list_indicator_font_size' => '7', // Bullet indicator size.
        'pseudo_list_indicator_character' => 'l ', // Gives a circle bullet point with wingdings.
        'table_allowed' => TRUE, // Note, if you are adding this html into a PHPWord table you should set this to FALSE: tables cannot be nested in PHPWord.
        'treat_div_as_paragraph' => TRUE, // If set to TRUE, each new div will trigger a new line in the Word document.
        // Optional - no default:
        'style_sheet' => htmltodocx_styles_example(), // This is an array (the "style sheet") - returned by htmltodocx_styles_example() here (in styles.inc) - see this function for an example of how to construct this array.
    );
    htmltodocx_insert_html($section, $html_dom_array[0]->nodes, $initial_state);
    $html_dom->clear();
    unset($html_dom);
}
```

I can't find any way to get '<' sign. while calling this function, just call with parameter like p<10.

Comment: Please update your PHP source.

Comment: At what line of the file does this error occur?

Comment: when I send 'p < 20' as parameter for $html_data

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the source code for [`simple_html_dom::load()`](https://github.com/samacs/simple_html_dom/blob/master/simple_html_dom.php#L1043), it appears as though the library parses data until it sees a `<` character. Then, it tries to create a new [`simple_html_dom_node`](https://github.com/samacs/simple_html_dom/blob/master/simple_html_dom.php#L110) using this data (which is not actually a DOM Node) and fails.

---

This library should already do this (and, if it were an actively maintained library, you could probably raise an issue with them to have it updated), but you can just encode the data with [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) before loading it into Simple HTML DOM.

```
$html_data = htmlentities($html_data);
// '<' is now '&lt;'

$html_dom = new \simple_html_dom();
$html_dom->load('<html><body>' . $html_data . '</body></html>');
```

Comment: After this in loading Ms word file it gives error like illegal qualified name character error.

Comment: @Subhod30 does `$html_data = str_replace('<', '&lt;', $html_data);` work (instead of `htmlentities()`)?